# why i can not search #enable-unsafe-webgpu in chrome://flags in windows chromeV95

Tags: webgpu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuyEQ.png)

In windows chromeV95,i input chrome://flags and search #enable-unsafe-webgpu, and there is no result ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to programming

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Normally one would like to experiment with and test developed features.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same with Chrome, but available in Chromium Version 97.0.4677.0 (Developer Build) (64-bit).
[image]

Comment: But in the wiki of chrome (en.jinzhao.wiki/wiki/Google_Chrome_version_history) said WebGPU starts its origin trial in chromeV94 ?https://web.dev/gpu/#browser-support

Comment: Correct - Haven't tried, then I think one shall register as Origin Trail https://developer.chrome.com/blog/origin-trials. Maybe the enable flag also will work with dev/canary versions of Chrome. Not sure, but think the experimental flags don't work for stable Chrome.